# zookeeper doen's get started due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I searched this forum already, no working answer is found for my case:

1. I installed java 1.8
2. I downloaded the binary version of zookeeper-3.5.5 from https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.5.5/apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin.tar.gz
3. I changed the zoo_sample.cfg to zoo.cfg, no changes made to the cfg
4. I tried to start zookeeper as root:

   [root@pocdnr1n1 apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin]# bin/zkServer.sh start conf/zoo.cfg

I received error in log:

```
Could not find the main class: org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.  Program will exit.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the root cause, posting it here for future readers:

The culprit is Java.

I had an old java version on the node, this can be verified by running `java -version`

In my case the java was 1.6, what I did is to reset the environment to add the new java 1.8 to it:

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_151
# export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/
# export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/bin
```

You should add the PATH to the .bash_profile so that it becomes permanent.

Now after that you run `source .bash_profile`, now you have set java 1.8 as the default java. again, you can confirm that by running `java -version`

Run your zookeeper again and it will be started as expected.

The common missings here are:

1. downloaded the non-binary zookeeper
2. java is too low (1.6 doesn't work, 1.8 is recommended)
3. environment should be set to ensure java 1.8 is picked up as default version

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [ZooKeeper Administrator's Guide - Required Software](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.5/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_requiredSoftware) for 3.5.5 it says:

> ZooKeeper runs in Java, release 1.7 or greater (JDK 7 or greater, FreeBSD support requires openjdk7).

which affirms what you found out.  Your Java version was too low.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was rebuilding with `./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion-2.13.10`

I was using kafka straight from source from github.com/apache/kafka and that step was given to me when I cloned a fresh copy of the repo to start from scratch.

I had done a git pull on my old version, so it broke the dependencies, which I forgot I must have at one point installed.